# setup include path in eclipse CDT in mac os (headers from framework)

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks, include

for example I need to include a header

```
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>
```

while it is actually a header file glext.h under OpenGL.framework/Headers/.
Therefore it is no way to give eclipse a physical path about "OpenGL/glext.h", and I always get unresolved inclusion warning.

I can still build and run them (with managed makefile project) but it is impossible to browse the functions or definitions from those "resolved" header files.

is there any solution?

Comment: it seems a bug in cdt https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=69529#c37

Comment: yeah it is a bug. 2 years later still not resolved. Workaround1: use Netbeans. Workaround2: add the framework folder in the includes

Answer (score 3):

While not ideal, my solution to this has been to create a folder "/Developer/Framework Headers" (though the name isn't important), and link from e.g. "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foo.framework/Headers" to "Foo" under said folder. Then in Eclipse I add "/Developer/Framework Headers" to a project's includes.

I say not ideal because apart from having to create links for the frameworks you need and add an include to each project, Eclipse seems to have trouble in certain cases such as nested frameworks (e.g. CoreGraphics beneath ApplicationServices), but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is one. Right click on the project in "Project Explore" window and click on the "property". In there Open "C/C++ General" column and choose "Path and symbols". Now you see all of the include library path for this project. If your using C then add the OpenGL library into GNU C, or if you use C++ then add it into GNU C++. Unfortunately you have to do this for every new project. I have been searching for a while how to do this by default but nothing really useful. Hope this help you get rid of those annoying yellow wave lines.

Comment: You described the normal process, but that doesn't work here, because there is no real path of "OpenGL/glext.h".  The Mac compiler translates that #include to "OpenGL.framework/Headers/glext.h" to find the file, but Eclipse doesn't understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Since current Eclipse CDT releases don't perform sub-framework header inclusion correctly, you can avoid sub-framework problems (like those generated by the CoreServices header files) by creating symbolic links to the include directories of each sub-framework. I elaborated on this subject, which stems from danhan answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067329/how-to-include-apple-frameworks-on-eclipse-cdt/21707202#21707202), in [this](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-include-apple-frameworks-headers.html) blog post.

In order to automate this process, I've created a Z shell script which automates this process and creates the symlink to the specified frameworks' header directory, together with the links to the include directory of each one of their sub-frameworks. The script can be found [in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/link-osx-framework-headers).

Hope this helps.