# Linking SDL2 framework-library with eclipse in mac osx

Tags: macos, linker, sdl-2

I've followed the SDL2 installing guide and placed the SDL2 framework folder under the /Library/Frameworks folder.

Now when trying to link the library with eclipse i found there is no library (.a) to link.

Somewhere i've read you can compile the library from the downloaded SDL folder. How is that done or how can i link the library in any other way?

Comment: I've seen there is a SDL2 Unix executable in a folder, but i don't know how to link it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem in my case came from 2 sides:

1. I had to add "-F/Library/Frameworks" before normally adding the SDL framework "-framework SDL2 -framework Cocoa" on the linker flags.
2. (and this one took me hours to solve) Reboot eclipse. Believe it or not. I'm not an eclipse expert so someone could bring some more light in here. I guess that when installing a new framework in OSX while your eclipse client is opened, that maybe forces you to reboot the client so the new framework can be linked in a project inside eclipse.

On the other side and to solve another issue you could find with the headers folder you can read the solution here:

[How to include Apple 'frameworks' on Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067329/how-to-include-apple-frameworks-on-eclipse-cdt)